# What are "contexts" in Mako?

Tags: python, mako

What is context in python, in particular what does `**context` mean? Is it a way to pass the variables in the current context around? A code example will be most appreciated.

```
from mako.template import Template
template = Template('var1 = ${var1}')
for v in range(1, 5):
  context = {'var1': v}
  print template.render(**context)
```

Comment: The word `context` has multiple uses in Python (e.g. `decimal` context and context managers). You will need to supply some more, well, context to the question.

Comment: In any case, all of these don't have anything to do with the `**` operator, which is just syntax for providing a dictionary as keywords to a function.

Comment: Ok sure thanks, how about this

Comment: from mako.template import Template

template = Template('var1 = ${var1}')

for v in range(1, 5):
    context = {'var1': v}
    print template.render(**context)

Comment: Sure, please apologize my ignorance, I am really trying to understand what does passing **context do in this case. I know what you are saying but trying to understand this snippet.

Comment: Isn't that the exact same code? oO It's equivalent to `template.render(var1=v)`, as I've said before. If you have problems understanding what that latter statement means, you gotta read up on keyword arguments in Python.

Comment: @user1247384, edit your question to include that code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case anything you pass to `render` as a kwarg is passed as a [Context](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/runtime.html#context) to your template in order to render.

The context represents a dictionary of data available to the page/template while rendering.  So when you do something like

```
 context = {'var1': v}
```

and your template has code like

```
$(var1)
```

It would print v

Mako resolves this by looking to the `Context`, which is just wraps a _data with the kwargs passed down to it via `render`.

Comment: It should be noted that this is nothing specific to templates. It's a Python feature that's used a lot, and in this particular case it would be much more sensible to supply the keyword explicitly instead of constructing a separate dict for it.

Comment: Correct kwargs/`**` is not a template thing, but the `context` is.

Answer (score 0):

The `**` operator, when it appears in a function call, converts a dictionary into a set of keyword arguments to a function. When it appears in a function definition, it converts a set of keyword arguments to a function into a dictionary. So for example:

```
>>> d = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
>>> def print_my_arguments(**my_arguments):
...     print my_arguments
... 
>>> print_my_arguments(a=0, b=1, c=2)
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
>>> print_my_arguments(**d)
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: @user1247384, did this help? Or did Nix's answer? It'd be nice to know whether this question is answered or not.